# Polimorphism vs inheritance

Tags: oop, inheritance, polymorphism

The process in which the newly created class uses elements of a more general class of already existing is inheritance, but is this also apply to the polymorphism?. I can't find in the internet an satisfying answer.

Comment: Your question is kind of fascinating in the way it's phrased.  I had to read it 4 times to parse it but it's near-perfect English.  I'm guessing you are not a native English speaker but either you ran this through a translator or you have a very good grasp on the grammar but don't get to use it much. I suggest considering re-ordering your sentences.  For instance, "I can't find a satisfying answer on the internet" or I understand that inheritance is... but...".  This comment is not intended to be critical--as I said your grammar is great! I just thought this suggestion might help in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Polymorphism is where two or more classes that either implement the same interface or extend the same parent can be substituted for each other.

An example is how a List and a HashTable are both Collections and may be substituted for each other when the object is defined as the general type (Collection)

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance is derived from the overall concept of polymorphism. Inheritance would be more specifically a type of Ad hoc polymorphism. The concept of an object oriented language in general is to allow features such as inheritance and abstraction. So inheritance allows the specialization of classes in say a hierarchical manner so then subclasses may inherit from a parent or more "general class", while Polymorphism allows you to use an object without knowing its exact type such as calling an inherited or virtual method and the language being able to get the correct method from many derivations or implementations of such method.